# SQL join not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, db2

I am trying to merge these two queries I have on a join but its not working out so well can you tell me where i'm going wrong. Thanks in advance

```
SELECT z1blto, 
       z1ctrk 
FROM   z1mast AS e 
JOIN   d 
       ( 
                select   a.ordprod, 
                         a.ordtotpcs , 
                         a.ordordnum, 
                         b.orhdate 
                FROM     dta/dw30d a 
                JOIN     dta/dw30c b 
                ON       a.ordcust = b.orhcust 
                AND      a.ordordnum = b.orhordnum 
                WHERE    a.ordcust = 'GL02' 
                AND      a.ordprod = '2002534B_GC' 
                ORDER BY b.orhdate) AS d 
ON     e.z1cucd = d.ordcust
```

Comment: how could we tell you that, when you only said to us: `its not working out so well`?, what does that mean?, what specifically isn't working?

Comment: Its not working at all, i'm new to joins so im not sure if the structure is right

Comment: Check your question please - what is the "d" in line 3 after the join and you did not select ordcust in the query...

Comment: but what does that mean?, is it throwing an error?, is it not returning results?, what specifically is happening?

Comment: @Lamak it just returning z1blto, z1ctrk fields its not joining to the other table

Comment: @JohnPublic I'm not sure if you are being serious or not. Of course it's returning those columns, because those are the columns in your `SELECT`, if you want more, then add them there: `SELECT z1blto,z1ctrk, ordprod, some_other_column`

Comment: That's all you ask for in your SELECT.

Comment: PS - go to Google and key in Mysql join tutorial.

Comment: Okay lol, i got you, i tried that and it work, but the field z1blto comes back empty. But they have data in them

Comment: Please add the relationships between tables to your question.  Ex. z1mast.id = dta/dw30d.id

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in your query. Your `ON` specification uses `ordcust` for a and `orhcust` for b, similarly for `ordornum` and `orddate`. Here is the corrected version. And you have an extra `d` before the nested query. I'm making some assumptions regarding spelling, as the information is missing from your questions.

```
SELECT z1blto, 
       z1ctrk 
FROM   z1mast AS e 
JOIN   
       ( 
                select   a.ordprod, 
                         a.ordtotpcs , 
                         a.ordordnum, 
                         b.orddate 
                FROM     dta/dw30d a 
                JOIN     dta/dw30c b 
                ON       a.ordcust = b.ordcust 
                AND      a.ordordnum = b.ordordnum 
                WHERE    a.ordcust = 'GL02' 
                AND      a.ordprod = '2002534B_GC' 
                ORDER BY b.orddate) AS d 
ON     e.z1cucd = d.ordcust
```